# How to get Google API refresh_token from code

Tags: curl, oauth-2.0, google-api, google-oauth

I try to get refresh token from code.
Here is curl I use:

```
curl --request POST --data "code=4/0AWtg..&client_id=977..&client_secret=GOC..&redirect_uri=htt..&grant_type=authorization_code" https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
```

returned value is

```
{
  "error": "invalid_grant",
  "error_description": "Bad Request"
}
```

What is wrong and how to get refresh_token from code, please?
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

invalid_grant is one of the most frequent oauth errors.  It can be caused by a number of things.

1. the code was already used
2. your PC time isn't set to NTP
3. The code and the client id don't match.

This is the code I use [GoogleAuthenticationCurl.sh](https://gist.github.com/LindaLawton/cff75182aac5fa42930a09f58b63a309)

```
curl \
--request POST \
--data "code=[Authentcation code from authorization link]&client_id=[Application Client Id]&client_secret=[Application Client Secret]&redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1&grant_type=authorization_code" \
https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/token
```

[Understand Google OAuth with curl](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hBC_tVJIx5w)

Comment: Yes, it works, but it does not help me :( Actually, my problem was because I used (to get a code) client_id for desktop application. I wanted to avoid usage of Authorised JavaScript origins and redirects. The reason is - my app will use different ports for different users (on same domain), like domain.com:3333, domain.com.3334 etc. If I use Desktop links, customer need to copy and paste code which I try to avoid. Is there any way to use Desktop link to get code without copy and paste it?

Comment: Awesome, your video explained it! Thank you

Comment: Well I would assume that you were not using curl with a customer.  Depending upon your chosen programming language your application should automatically open the consent screen window and then consume the authorization code it self.     If your using different ports then it sounds like you should be using a web app not an installed app anyway.

Comment: Yes, I can sort everything but the problem is that each customer use other port so I need manually add each link to Console.. is there any API to add Authorised JavaScript origins and redirects url's?

Comment: No you need to do it manually